# Where are package library and header files installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, dpkg

After downloading and installing a package in Ubuntu, how can I check where the library and header files were written to? I believe that this has something to do with the package's .pc file, but I do not know how to find that file either.

For example, I have downloaded the PCL (Point Cloud Library) package, and then in a sample CMakeLists.txt file, I have been given the following:

```
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Where are these environment variables defined, and how can I see them?

If I compiled the libraries from source rather than through a package, will this be any different? Will a .pc file be created automatically?

Comment: `echo $PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS`

Comment: That just returns an empty line. However, compiling my project as above works fine so it must be using the PCL libraries. Is it searching anywhere else?

Comment: If you installed a debian package you can see the content via dpkg -L <package name>. If you install from source, it depends heavily on the source and you need to familiarise yourself with the build system it uses.

Comment: @Karnivaurus Can you check if my answer is correct?

Comment: I had similar confusions. You can check to what values `${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}` resolves to by using `message` command in your `CMakeLists.txt` i.e. add this line: `message("${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})` or `message("PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS = " ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. It will display the result when you run `cmake ..` Do the same for other macros/variables i.e. `${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}` and `${PCL_DEFINITIONS}`

Answer (score 9):

If you install the package containing the libpcl development files

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev
```

You can list the installed files

```
dpkg -L libpcl-dev
```

an see the location of all headers.

```
...
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/fast_bilateral.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid_covariance.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid_occlusion_estimation.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/median_filter.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/crop_box.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/voxel_grid_label.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/covariance_sampling.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/random_sample.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/normal_refinement.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/project_inliers.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/fast_bilateral_omp.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/clipper3D.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/convolution.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/passthrough.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/conditional_removal.h
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/frustum_culling.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/conditional_removal.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/convolution_3d.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/voxel_grid_covariance.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/fast_bilateral_omp.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/project_inliers.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/morphological_filter.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/crop_box.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/covariance_sampling.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/local_maximum.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/plane_clipper3D.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/bilateral.hpp
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/filters/impl/voxel_grid_occlusion_estimation.hpp
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing such a useful command. When typed that in my Ubuntu 18.04 having PCL-1.8, I got a very long list. So, to understand more, `/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/` contains **PCL header** files; `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` contains **PCL libraries** (all the `.so` files), right? But what about other directories: `/usr/share/doc/libpcl-dev`; `/usr/share/doc/libpcl-dev/`; `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`. I mean what are they exactly called? I'm also trying to understand `CMakeLists.txt` for `PCL` projects so your answer would help me a lot in understanding that even better!

Answer (score 2):

By default libraries are installed in /usr/lib and header files will be in /usr/include

Usually extension of the library file is .so and corresponding header file will be .h

gui method for finding installed libraries is open software center->Developer tools-> Libraries